Electron-Forge add fileAssociation for an app for macOs and linux
I have an electron app built with electron-forge. i want to add the ability for my app that when a user right clicks on a txt file in his filesystem, the context menu will offer him to open the txt file with my electron app.
how and where do i configure file association in the electron-forge project?
in the forge.config.js file? the docs are not informative on this subject.
Which event listeners should i implement so i can do something with the txt file. for example - console.log the file path. this should work both in linux and macOs.

Electron-Forge doesn't provide any easy built-in feature for file association. You can find an open feature request about this in the repo issues.
macOS
File association can be configured with a Info.plist (Information Property List) file. You can link it to your config with the extendInfo option:
"electronPackagerConfig": {
  "extendInfo": "[path-to-file]/Info.plist"
}

Info.plist
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
  <array>
    <dict>
      <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
      <string>PNG image</string>
      <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
      <string>Editor</string>
      <key>CFBundleTypeMIMETypes</key>
      <array>
        <string>image/png</string>
      </array>
      <key>CFBundleTypeExtensions</key>
      <array>
        <string>png</string>
      </array>
    </dict>
    ...
  </array>
</dict>
</plist>

Or you can write the config directly as:
"electronPackagerConfig": {
  "extendInfo": {
    CFBundleDocumentTypes: [
      {
        CFBundleTypeName: "PNG image",
        CFBundleTypeRole: "Editor",
        CFBundleTypeMIMETypes: ["image/png"],
        CFBundleTypeExtensions: ["png"],
        ...
      },
    ],
  }
}

You can find examples of config in this issue as well as on this repo (but I haven't tried any of them personally).
Windows
You need to register the file in Windows registry on install.
I have not found many examples of code for this, except maybe for the ones on this related question, and also the source code of this library, which actually claims to provide this feature (but doesn't seem well maintained). There is also a (somehow) related discussion on this Squirrel.Windows issue.
If you use Electron Forge's WiX MSI maker, you can use the property associateExtensions, which is a comma-seperated string of extensions. By default, each extension will be associated with your app icon, so you need to specify its full path (relative paths don't work). If you need the extension to be linked to another icon than the app icon, you will need to edit the property fileAssociationTemplate on the MSICreator using the beforeCreate method:
{
  config: {
    icon: path.join(process.cwd(), 'assets', 'icon.ico'),
    associateExtensions: 'ext',
  },
  beforeCreate: (creator: WixCreator) => {
    // Manually convert app icon to some other icon
    // Manipulate the `fileAssociationTemplate`
  },
} satisfies ExtendedMakerWixConfig

If you use TypeScript, you will also need to override the config by extending MakerWixConfig to include the property:
interface ExtendedMakerWixConfig extends MakerWixConfig {
  // This is an undocumented property of `electron-wix-msi`
  // See https://github.com/electron/forge/issues/3673
  associateExtensions?: string;
}

Linux
I was not able to find any useful information. I believe you have to do a custom code as for Windows. Here is a tutorial on how to associate file types to applications on Linux.

As an alternative, electron-builder provides file associations out-of-the-box with the fileAssociations option available in the common configuration.
